# markov-switching model and stationarity

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, statistics, time-series, stata

To test the structural breaks and to perform markov-switching model  in time series data,  should i have stationary data.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In [this lecture](https://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~ckuan/pdf/Lec-Markov_note.pdf) it is stated at chapter 2.3 that *"The Markov switching model and its variants discussed in the preceding sections are
only suitable for stationary data"*. Perhaps you'd like to read into that more thoroughly.

*Possible solution*:

Since differentiation is allowed, you should also be able to produce an Error-Correcting Model -and its variants- through *cointegration* if stationarity is not achieved.